# How can I use dplyr and magrittr to pipe a data manipulation into a function that requires a numeric vector?

Tags: r, type-conversion, dplyr

I am trying to use dplyr and magrittr to pipe a data manipulation into a function that wants a numeric vector as its input. Specifically, I'm hoping to have the result of my piping go into the ecdf() function (which generates an empirical cumulative distribution function from a vector).

Here is what I would like to work:

```
x = rnorm(100)
t = sample(c("A","B"), replace = TRUE)
df = data.frame(x,t)
df_ecdf = filter(df, x > 0) %>%
  filter(t == "A") %>%
  select(x) %>%
  as.vector() %>%
  ecdf()
```

However, that doesn't work, because ecdf() gives the error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

which makes sense, because the piping up through as.vector() doesn't actually result in a vector of data. It results in a list, that I don't know how to use piping to convert into a numeric vector.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

As answered by BrodieG below, the solution was to pipe into unlist before ecdf, and also didn't require parentheses (as per Ananda Mahto):

```
df_ecdf = filter(df, x > 0) %>%
  filter(t == "A") %>%
  select(x) %>%
  unlist %>%
  ecdf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `unlist`?

```
filter(df, x > 0) %>%
  filter(t == "A") %>%
  select(x) %>%
  unlist %>%
  ecdf
```

Or:

```
filter(df, x > 0) %>%
  filter(t == "A") %>%
  `[[`("x") %>%
  ecdf
```

However, you should consider using `base` R for this type of task:

```
ecdf(subset(df, x > 0 & t == "A", x, drop=T))
```

Or even if you must:

```
df %>% subset(x > 0 & t == "A", x, drop=T) %>% ecdf
```

Comment: And if I'm not mistaken, the `()` are unnecessary (+1)

Comment: `magrittr` provides a number of alias functions that are supposed to replace `[`, `[[` etc. For example, `extract2` is an alias for `[[` so that you can use `extract2("x")` instead of `'[['("x")` in the second solution.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are asking for a dplyr / magrittr solution you could use magrittr's `%$%` operator which is designed for this specific task of extracting a column of a data.frame as a vector:

```
library(dplyr); library(magrittr)

df_ecdf = filter(df, x > 0) %>%
  filter(t == "A") %$%
  x %>%
  ecdf
```